# Remove a linebreak after IMG

Tags: html, css

I have an img element set next to a div. I have tried a couple of different approaches to remove the linebreak that is occurring between the two but have not had any success. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

CSS

```
#newsMainBody
{
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background:#61bc49;
width: 750px;
height: 900px;
font-family:"sans-serif";
text-align:left;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;/*mozilla*/
z-index: 1;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#starOfMonth
{
background: #ffff99;
width: 275px;
height: 300px;
text-align: center;
font-family:"sans-serif";
white-space: normal;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="newsMainBody">
   <img src="img/farm.jpg" alt="Farm photo" />
   <div id="starOfMonth">
      <br />
      <font style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium; color:Purple;">DooLittle Farms Childcare</font><br />
      <font style="font-size:small;">"We're Growing Great Kids"</font><br />
      <img id="starImg" src="img/gold-star.jpg" alt="Star of the Week" width="200" height="200"/><br />
      Our Star Of The Week!
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What two elements are you referring to? The image and?

Comment: The img and the div id=#starOfMonth elem. When I preview in any browser, the div elem is directly underneath the img elem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add:

```
#newsMainBody img {
float: left;
}

#startOfMonth {
float: right;
}
```

and remove the first `<br />` after `<div id="starOfMonth">`, it's useless (use padding-top in css instead if you need some space)

Comment: This did the trick with some minor ajustments such as additing some margin to the left and right to properly space the elements

Comment: In addition, I didn't do it to the newMainBody elem because that would cause the entire body to float left whereas I wanted it centered. So I just wrapped the img in a new div tag and floated that instead. Thanks everyone for their input!

Answer (score 1):

Try making the image and the div float:left; You **WILL** need to provide a width for each to make this work.

```
#starOfMonth
{
background: #ffff99;
float: left;
width: 275px;
height: 300px;
text-align: center;
font-family:"sans-serif";
white-space: normal;
}

#starOfMonthImage {
height:275px; /*Optional, but it's a good idea to supply height for images so that the browser doesn't shift things around during the loading process*/
width:475px; /*OR SOMETHING!  Make it narrower if it isn't working, I haven't been super careful about reading your padding in depth so this may be wrong.*/
float:left;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
<div id="newsMainBody">
   <img src="img/farm.jpg" alt="Farm photo" id="starOfMonthImage" />
   <div id="starOfMonth">
      <br />
      <font style="font-weight:bold;font-size:medium; color:Purple;">DooLittle Farms Childcare</font><br />
      <font style="font-size:small;">"We're Growing Great Kids"</font><br />
      <img id="starImg" src="img/gold-star.jpg" alt="Star of the Week" width="200" height="200"/><br />
      Our Star Of The Week!
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption you're referring to the one with the alt-text of `Farm photo`:

```
div#newsMainBody > img {
/*        display: block; commented out as per @M2tM's comment, below */
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
#starOfMonth {
    margin-left: 200px; /* or 'width of floated image' + 'a margin of 10px' 
}                       /* or whatever, just so they're not physically touching */
```

Should achieve this, but I'm unsure why you've got a floating `<br />` inside the `#starOfMonth` div. That might be a problem.

Live demo, [over at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/osuro4/) (obviously the `image`s don't load (given the `src` isn't pointing at anything, but it should give you a feel for what my approach does.)

Comment: That is just to bring the text down one line for better formatting. I will give this a try

Comment: First: you need to specify a width or it won't float properly.  Second: The floating <br/> inside the div will not affect the way it lays out next to the image, it will add a break inside the div. Third: display:block; is unnecessary as float:left; will override this.  In fact, IE6 sometimes requires display:inline; to be applied to floating elements with a margin in order to fix the IE float bug.

Comment: @M2tM, okay. In order, then: 1. yes, I realised that. Hence the edits. 2. I never said it did, I just wondered why it was there. 3. fair enough, and thanks for taking the time to point that out.

Comment: Good, I've removed my -1 vote, but again, I already had the correct solution posted before...